# Checksum failed while bitbake

Tags: ftp, md5sum, binutils

I am using ubuntu 12.04 to build gumstix-microwindows-image. However I am getting this error when I do bitbake gumstix-microwindows-image

NOTE: Handling BitBake files: | (4957/4958) [99 %]ERROR: opening /home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/user.collection/packages/*/*.bb: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/user.collection/packages/*/*.bb'

NOTE: Parsing finished. 4721 cached, 0 parsed, 236 skipped, 0 masked.
NOTE: build 201412160820: started

OE Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION     = "1.8.10"

OE_REVISION    = ""

TARGET_ARCH    = "arm"

TARGET_OS      = "linux-gnueabi"

MACHINE        = "gumstix-custom-verdex"

DISTRO         = "angstrom"
DISTRO_VERSION = "2007.9-test-20141216"
TARGET_FPU     = "soft"

NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

NOTE: preferred version 2.5 of glibc not available (for item virtual/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-libc-for-gcc)
NOTE: Preparing runqueue
NOTE: Executing runqueue

NOTE: Running task 69 of 1431 (ID: 337, /home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/org.openembedded.snapshot/packages/binutils/binutils-cross_2.18.bb, do_fetch)

NOTE: package binutils-cross-2.18: started
NOTE: package binutils-cross-2.18-r1: task do_fetch: started

NOTE: The MD5Sums did not match. Wanted: '9d22ee4dafa3a194457caf4706f9cf01' and Got: 'ccd264a5fa9ed992a21427c69cba91d3'

NOTE: Task failed: Checksum of 'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.18.tar.bz2' failed

NOTE: package binutils-cross-2.18-r1: task do_fetch: failed

ERROR: TaskFailed event exception, aborting

NOTE: package binutils-cross-2.18: failed

ERROR: Build of /home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/org.openembedded.snapshot/packages/binutils/binutils-cross_2.18.bb do_fetch failed

ERROR: Task 337 (/home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/org.openembedded.snapshot/packages/binutils/binutils-cross_2.18.bb, do_fetch) failed

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 68 tasks of which 68 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

ERROR: '/home/hassam/gumstix/gumstix-oe/org.openembedded.snapshot/packages/binutils/binutils-cross_2.18.bb' failed

Comment: hi there... either [How to configure LIC_FILE_CHECKSUM for https downloads in SRC_URI in Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700957/how-to-configure-lic-file-checksum-for-https-downloads-in-src-uri-in-yocto) or [Turn off Source Checksum Check Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501692/turn-off-source-checksum-check-yocto) should be helpful. If you're using 1st case then try to update checksum with newer one, there could be chance that it has been updated online, but need to update recipe as well.